# Can you host a Java swing app inside a WPF app?

Tags: java, wpf, swing, jvm

I suppose the question I'm asking is it possible to host a JVM inside a WPF application?

WPF = Windows Presentation Foundation

Found this so far:

http://www.jnbridge.com/jnbp-examples.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can P/invoke out to anything, you could create a native c/c++ library that starts up the vm and does whatever other things you need, and then call methods on it from c#.

If you're going to try to host UI stuff, then something like jnbridge would probably be useful instead of trying to roll all that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you found looks reasonable.

Otherwise, you could look at [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net) and see if you can use that to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like John Gardner says, here's a good [example](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1264492) of using [`JNI_CreateJavaVM`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502).